# Figures inside environments

Tags: floats

Assume I have a figure to illustrate an example.
Is the correct way to typeset

```
\begin{example}
…
\begin{figure}
…
\end{figure}
\end{example}
```

or

```
\begin{example}
…
\end{example}

\begin{figure}
…
\end{figure}
```

or maybe even

```
\begin{figure}
…
\end{figure}

\begin{example}
…
\end{example}
```

with, in all the cases, a reference from the text in the example to the figure?

Comment: Perhaps give us a minimal working example using `\usepackage{mwe}`: http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/mwe.pdf

Comment: I would probably place it outside and just refer to it. Then you still have the freedom to say frame the example later on. Placing it inside will not guarantee that it stays there anyway

Comment: Depending on how `example` is defined, the float can be lost inside the `example` environment, so placing outside is the better option, I think.

Comment: How does your example environment look like?

Comment: the _only_ purpose of a `figure` environment is to mark the content as something that is not in the main document flow and can be inserted as needed by latex at a position that helps with page breaking. so your third form is almost always the required one, and depending on the definition of `example` the other two may do the wrong thing or give an error.

Comment: I did not provide a MWE or more precisions on purpose, because I believed there was a generic answer to that question. Thanks a lot, @DavidCarlisle, for your comment. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only purpose of a `figure` environment is to mark the content as something that is not in the main document flow and can be inserted as needed by latex at a position that helps with page breaking.

So your third form is almost always the required one, and depending on the definition of `example` the other two may do the wrong thing or give an error.